# is there a word for arguing no one?

Tags: american-english

I'm wondering if there is a word for when someone is making an argument but there is no one on the other side of the argument. it's like they've made a statement against an opinion, even though no one has stated said opinion. i want to claim it's a logical fallacy too, but i am unsure. thank you

Comment: They might be **tilting at windmills** - *To attack imaginary enemies.* - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tilt_at_windmills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term '**preaching to the choir**' describes a situation in which one is professing a conviction to someone whom they believe to be opposed, but is actually in agreement.

'Preaching' is generally the act of giving moral guidance to those believed to be immoral. 'The choir' is the group singing about that same morality, and are presumably moral.

Misconstruing the argument of someone who is in fact opposed to you in order to attack them is called a '**straw man argument**'. A 'straw man' is a stand-in for a real man, and thus the 'straw man argument' is a stand-in for a more formidable argument, which one can attack with ease.

Comment: +1 for *preaching to the choir*  One might also be *playing devil's advocate.*

Comment: Devil's advocate. That's a fun one. In that case, however, the person arguing knows they're not necessarily in conflict, but the audience might not. The opposite situation of 'preaching...'. Imagery is conveniently opposite, as well :)

Comment: It's known in certain circles as an 'Eastwood' Gambit."

Comment: thank you, i've heard that phrase before. i looked into "preaching to the choir" more and found that it is "Often used to imply that a speaker is addressing the wrong audience or is deliberately addressing a compliant, non-challenging audience." which is what i was looking for. i wonder if it can be used as a challenge statement though, example "why are you preaching to the choir?"

Comment: @joachim It's not often used to challenge someone so much as to calm them down, or even join with them. Generally, when someone is heated and arguing, if you tell them you agree with them, they'll cool down. Accusatory phrases won't help to mend the situation. 'You're preaching to the choir.' as a statement of fact is the most common usage.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually said is not a logical fallacy.

But a related fallacy is the "straw man" argument.

[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)

> The so-called typical "attacking a straw man" argument creates the illusion of having completely refuted or defeated an opponent's proposition by covertly replacing it with a different proposition (i.e., "stand up a straw man") and then to refute or defeat that false argument ("knock down a straw man") instead of the original proposition.